# How many different sets $T$ can be written?

Tags: combinatorics

$$A = \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$$

$$B= \{{a,b}\}$$

How many different sets $T$ can be written as it will be $B\subseteq T\subseteq A$?

I know that it will involve $\{{a,b}\}$ because of $B \subseteq T$. However, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ will have to be of the form $T = \{a, b\} \cup S$, where $S$ is a subset of $A\setminus B = \{c, d, e, f\}$. Since $S$ can be arbitrary, there are $2^{|A\setminus B|} = 2^4 = 16$ possibilities for $S$.

Thus, there are $16$ possible sets $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To get $T$ you should chose a subset in $\{c,d,e,f\}$ and then take union with $\{a,b\}$.